# Redundant Get Requests on Site and Some Cancelled Requests

Tags: wordpress, apache, get, request, google-chrome-devtools

This might be an obvious question for the stackoverflow community but I am struggling finding answers and have depleted my resources in finding a solution.

I have a webpage [EBDesigns.us](http://ebdesigns.us). Now, when I open my chrome browser's dev tools, under the Network tab. I can view all get requests made to the server.

The largest files transferred are my images but why are there multiple get requests to the same image files? i.e. Capa-972x1024-compressor.png.

Also, why are there some image files with cancelled get requests.

How can I make it so that I call a resources only once? What can I do to debug this issue?

I am trying to consolidate the transferred file sizes by reducing the number of requests made.

Any time spent on this topic is much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like maybe there's an extension that is intercepting your HTTP requests. I'm not getting multiple requests to the same resources, nor am I getting cancelled requests on your website.

Comment: You were right, it's an extension. Tried it in a different browser/ computer. Weird...

Comment: Disable extensions one at a time to see which one may be causing it. If you create a new Chrome Profile, you won't experience the issue either as it will be a clean environment.